# UITabBarController shouldSelectViewController not pushing view controller Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have 4 items in a tab bar and one will open an UIAlertController. I already done this however, how can I show this modally? It shows the view controller with a black bg instead. I've read from other posts that I should override shouldSelectViewController but it seems that it doesn't even get there. I tried printing something but nothing shows.

Here's my code. Should I add this code in the class for the tabBarController or in the AppDelegate? What vc does it actually present below? I'm really stuck here. I have screenshot as well

[Screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QKje.png)

```
 func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController!, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController!) -> Bool {

        if viewController is SellUploadViewController {
            if let newVC = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sellUploadVC") {
                tabBarController.present(newVC, animated: true)
                return false
            }
        }

        return true


}
```

Comment: Are you saying that one of the UITabBarControllers.viewControllers is a UIAlertController?  If so, i think this what you are doing is incorrect and the results you are getting are correct.  I'll explain more when you confirm my initial question.

Comment: HI @BrianTrzupek. Yes. One bar item is link to an empty view controller that has a function to call a UIAlertController in viewDidLoad(). It opens perfectly as in the image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I am a bit confused on the view controller hierarchy then. Is it UITabBarController->Some ViewController->UIAlertController?

Comment: Yes exactly. In Instagram before, when you click the camera on the tab bar, it will open the UIAlertController with camera and gallery options. That's what I need to happen. In my case now, the UIAlertController opens but the viewcontroller is showing.I need this to be transparent. Any idea?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are trying to do. I did a similar thing in my app Dibs for the same exact purpose. That is a obj-c project, but i can post the specific code if you like anyways. What I ended up doing was setting up a viewController that would present my 'data collection' (camera) views in a new Navigation Controller, so i could walk though the steps nicely. When they were complete with their post, I posted a NotificationCenter notification back to the viewController that presented the NavigationController and capture process. That notification would then close the nav and go to tab 0 (feed

Comment: Thank you! that sounds interesting. Can I see the code?